# Найти все устройства в сети wi-fi используя Андроид

Tags: java, android, сеть, wifi

В сети подключены к модему arduino и андроид, как найти эти устройства в сети?(Нужны только ip)
Если к этой сети подключить компьютер на windows и в cmd написать ***arp -a***, то выводит все устройства.
Какой есть аналог подобным действиям на андроид или java? По плану используемый api 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поискав пару дополнительных часиков, было найдено несколько методов:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221517/how-to-get-subnet-mask-of-local-system-using-java?newreg=45f52d8038534b40841ef70f47e4e780
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277912/how-to-scan-ip-in-android